# Can "is-a" and "has-a" existed at the same time?

Tags: uml

Assume there are two class, Class `B` is subclass Class `A` and `B` has a property `a` which is kind of `A`, as pseudo code below show:

```
class A {}

class B extends A { 
     A a; 
}
```

In UML word, there are two relationships between class `B` and class `A`. `B` 'is-a' kind of `A` on while `B` 'has-a' property of `A`. Can I represented these relationships at the same time in one class diagram?

[image]

When I google this, it is common that only one relationship existed between two class in all results. So I am not sure whether it is allowed to draw diagram like this. If not, how UML to express this kind of relationships between classes.

Comment: If you think logically,I don;t think so it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most common application of this approach is known as [Composite design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern), very often used to represent tree-like data structures.

This pattern gives you possibility not only to represent a tree (hierarchy) but also effectively and uniformly process it (via appropriate *operation()* implementations).

[image: Composite pattern]

**EDIT**

When writing this answer I completely forgot about the other widely used [Decorator design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) which is used to augment functionality of Component by inheritance & inclusion, in opposite to simply extending it in cases when straightforward overriding of methods not possible or appropriate.

[image: Decorator pattern]

Answer (score 3):

Of course it's possible. Example: a Human Being is a kind of Animal and can have an Animal as a pet. (Although one may want rules prohibiting Human Beings as pets. :-) )

One thing that absolutely will *not* work, however, is making the minimum cardinality 1. That would mean that every pet must also have a pet!

Beware that your text, pseudo code, and UML don't match. Your UML diagram uses a *composition*, which means that when the pet in my example dies, the owner must also die! To fix this, you can use the white diamond.

Comment: Bad example. It's an example of mismatch between the english meaning of "having" vs. UML. The OP describes a composition relation, i.e. lifetime of object B is coupled with lifetime of object A. This is definitely not the case in your example.

Comment: That would be a fair point if the OP's text and pseudo code matched the diagram. Even in your answer you don't have an example of composition.

Comment: @JimL. Are you sure you understand *what is* composition? Both the question and my answer state it pretty clearly.

Comment: The UML 2.5 draft I have on hand says, "[composition] Indicates that the Property is aggregated compositely, i.e., the composite object has responsibility for the **existence and storage** of the composed objects (parts)." (Emphasis is mine.) In your example, which I assume is Java, you don't have control over the storage of `a` (i.e., it's not embedded in the memory allocated to a RedCircle instance), and if you pass `a` to another class' operation and that class saves it, that instance of `A` may outlive the containing instance of `RedCircle`.

Comment: @JimL. it's an instance variable that is bounded to the lifetime of the object. Implementation details are omitted

Answer (score 1):

The classical example for this is:

A=Piece
B=CompositePiece (which is made of other pieces, either composite or not)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, though infrequent. Remember that a class is an abstract entity, that can have several distinct *instances*, allowing us to have such constructions.

For example, a red circle containing a circle:

[image: Red circle contains a circle]

```
class Circle {}

class RedCircle extends Circle { 
     Circle a; 
     //...
     //more stuff for the red property
}
```

Comment: Is there any UML specification description for this?

Answer (score -1):

You absolutely can.

One example where you may use this is some kind of custom LinkedList where you want each of your nodes to be a different subclass for some reason. In this case, the nodes will be of the type node, but also contain references to the next/previous node.

As for how to express this in UML, I see no reason why you can't have two lines linking the same two boxes - After all, it does have two separate relationships.

Comment: A better example would be a scene graph. Basically a tree where the parent class contains a collection of children of some base class.

Comment: This is not the case. It would've been suitable for non-composite aggregation

Comment: Is there any UML specification description for this?